# Shell script executes fail

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I wrote a shell script for restart celery. My os is Ubuntu 16.04.3.
I try to run this shell script, just killed celery processes, but not start
a new celery processes. Why?
This is my code.

```
ps -ef | grep celery | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v grep |xargs kill -9;
celery -A loan_app.tasks worker --loglevel=info  --workdir=`pwd` --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery_pid -D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official documentation: 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html
Please read the text highlighted in bold.

Stopping the worker
Shutdown should be accomplished using the TERM signal.

When shutdown is initiated the worker will finish all currently executing tasks before it actually terminates. If these tasks are important, you should wait for it to finish before doing anything drastic, like sending the KILL signal.

If the worker won’t shutdown after considerate time, for being stuck in an infinite-loop or similar, you can use the KILL signal to force terminate the worker: but be aware that currently executing tasks will be lost (i.e., unless the tasks have the acks_late option set).

**Also as processes can’t override the KILL signal, the worker will not be able to reap its children; make sure to do so manually. This command usually does the trick:**

$ **pkill -9 -f** 'celery worker'
If you don’t have the pkill command on your system, you can use the slightly longer version:

$ **ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9**

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use like below it will solve your issue:-

1. IF you just want to stop all the instances of process `celery` use below command

   ```
    ps -ef | grep [c]elery |awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
   ```
2. If you want to stop all the instances of process `celery` and re-start it again use below command

ps -ef | grep [c]elery |awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

```
 pids=$(ps -ef | grep [c]elery |awk '{print $2}')

 if [ "$pids" != "" ]; then
     PWD=$(pwd)    
     celery -A loan_app.tasks worker --loglevel=info  --workdir=$PWD --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery_pid -D

 else
      echo "Failed to kill process celery"
 fi
```

3. Straight forward example:-

   ```
   ps -ef | grep [c]elery |awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
   PWD=$(pwd)    
   celery -A loan_app.tasks worker --loglevel=info  --workdir=$PWD --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery_pid -D
   ```

Comment: What out put your are getting? This line  "Failed to kill process celery"? What I understood is that you want to stop all the instances of `celery` process and once stopped you want to re-starts `celery` right?

Comment: Can you please execute `ps -ef | grep [c]elery` in your system and provide me the output?

Comment: Just output Killed in terminal.

Comment: You don't want to re-start `celery`? Just use `ps -ef | grep [c]elery |awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Yes, I need to restart processes, Your code just kill process, but not start new process.

Comment: @Yang, I have modified my answer. You have problem in restarting the process. Validate the command whether it is correct or not.

Comment: It doesn't work still. I just look up official documentation, using  pkill -9 -f 'celery worker' or  ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9  to kill process , would be resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a miskate in following command.

```
ps -ef | grep celery | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v grep |xargs kill -9;
```

It should be as following

```
ps -ef | grep celery | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9;
```

You are excluding "grep" process after taking just process ids and you can never find grep process id

Hope this helps